# Python Pandas - Combining Multiple Columns into one Staggered Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do you combine multiple columns into one staggered column? For example, if I have data:

```
  Column 1 Column 2
0        A        E
1        B        F
2        C        G
3        D        H
```

And I want it in the form:

```
  Column 1 
0        A       
1        E       
2        B       
3        F       
4        C       
5        G       
6        D       
7        H
```

What is a good, vectorized pythonic way to go about doing this? I could probably do some sort of df.apply() hack but I'm betting there is a better way. The application is putting multiple dimensions of time series data into a single stream for ML applications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First stack the columns and then drop the multiindex:

```
df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
Out: 
0    A
1    E
2    B
3    F
4    C
5    G
6    D
7    H
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 6):

To get a dataframe:

```
 pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1, 1), columns=['Column 1'])
```

[image]

For a series answering OP question:

```
 pd.Series(df.values.flatten(), name='Column 1')
```

For a series timing tests:

```
pd.Series(get_df(n).values.flatten(), name='Column 1')
```

---

#### Timing

**code**

```
def get_df(n=1):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Column 2': {0: 'E', 1: 'F', 2: 'G', 3: 'H'},
                       'Column 1': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D'}})
    return pd.concat([df for _ in range(n)])
```

**Given Sample**

[image]

**Given Sample * 10,000**

[image]

**Given Sample * 1,000,000**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Another great answer. I wonder how it compares in speed to the df.stack() method.

Comment: @sfortney, ayhan's is better.

Comment: Good to know. That's what my prior was too.

Comment: actually, maybe not.  I'll do more analysis

Comment: @piRSquared I haven't tested it but here we know the shape so your solution makes use of that. I'd expect it to be faster.

Comment: @ayhan you're returning a series, I return a dataframe.  That makes a subtle difference in timing.  If I change my answer to return a series, I can compare apples to apples.  I'll have something in a few minutes.

Comment: @sfortney conclusion is that they are basically the same.  Except ayhan's is better as it's just as fast and pure pandas ;-)

Comment: I think get_df function is dominating the results. When I test it, yours is definitely faster. :)

Comment: @ayhan you're right.  I'll won't do that again.  Include dataframe creation in test, that is :-)

Comment: @Merlin yeah... I wanted to compare against ayhan's series.  reshape(-1, 1) gave me 2-D.  Flatten gave me 1-D very elegantly.  I'll edit post to make it more obvious.